# An approximation for $1\leq n\leq N$ of the number of solutions of $2^{\pi(n)}\equiv 1\text{ mod }n$, where $\pi(x)$ is the prime-counting function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, congruences, prime-factorization

We denote the prime-counting function with $\pi(x)$ and we consider integer solutions $n\geq 1$ of the congruence $$2^{\pi(n)}\equiv 1\text{ mod }n.\tag{1}$$
Then the sequence of solutions starts as $$1,3,39,43,63,91\ldots$$

> **Question.** I would like to know if it is possible to get an approximation for the number of solutions of $(1)$ when $n$ runs over the segment of integers $1\leq n\leq N$ ( we assume that for some large integer $N$). What work can be done? **Many thanks.**

You can compute more solutions using this code

`for (n = 1, 10000,if (Mod(2^(primepi(n)),n)==1,print(n)))`

from this [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) (choose *GP* as language and press *Evaluate*).

Comment: Perhaps it's a good idea to try and prove your congruence even has infinitely many solutions; however even that seems quite the task.

Comment: I am agree with your words, many thanks for your help @vrugtehagel

Comment: Since 2 is co- prime with any odd number, $\pi(n)$ is  actually identical to $\phi(n)$ in congruence $2^{\phi(n)} ≡ 1 \mod n$ .

Comment: Many thanks @sirous I don't understand well your comment, see the code `for (n = 1, 100,if (Mod(2^(eulerphi(n)),n)==1,print(n)))`

Comment: A larger solution is $$n=\color \red {4\ 001\ 691\ 757}$$

Comment: Many thanks is an incredible large number @Peter solving the congruence

Comment: If it can be proven that infinite many solutions exist ? Or what would be even more surprising : that infinite many prime solutions exist ?

Comment: Good candidates for large solutions are large Mersenne prime factors $p$ because they have a small order modulo $2$, so the chance that $\pi(p)$ is a multiple of the order is relatively high.

Comment: Many thanks for these nice remarks, and the calculations below @Peter

Answer (score 0):

The $\color\red {473}$ solutions upto $n=10^7$ are :

```
? x=0;y=1;forstep(n=1,10^7,2,if(isprime(n,2)==1,y=y+1);if(Mod(y,znorder(Mod(2,n)
))==0,x=x+1;print(x,"   ",n)))
1   1
2   3
3   39
4   43
5   63
6   91
7   365
8   435
9   1085
10   1285
11   2431
12   3283
13   4095
14   4287
15   4411
16   5205
17   5235
18   5797
19   6477
20   11565
21   12025
22   14577
23   14705
24   16861
25   17195
26   17391
27   20247
28   20447
29   24303
30   24309
31   28055
32   28655
33   29925
34   30569
35   33025
36   33789
37   35113
38   38961
39   39339
40   39975
41   41899
42   45339
43   45885
44   46683
45   46815
46   49477
47   49981
48   50511
49   54093
50   56355
51   57159
52   59367
53   60357
54   65365
55   79105
56   81915
57   82899
58   83333
59   90699
60   100113
61   107091
62   116685
63   122269
64   122773
65   127697
66   130247
67   137139
68   142569
69   146783
70   152427
71   153035
72   155085
73   157165
74   163845
75   165353
76   176583
77   180467
78   186817
79   188513
80   199465
81   199471
82   200907
83   207205
84   208143
85   215749
86   217455
87   217965
88   220533
89   228795
90   232565
91   258075
92   272571
93   279527
94   284937
95   287513
96   299013
97   309097
98   313325
99   316533
100   317985
101   329311
102   333785
103   333861
104   335153
105   338045
106   338055
107   338085
108   342693
109   343525
110   351075
111   351715
112   369721
113   394755
114   398071
115   410483
116   426839
117   448923
118   462099
119   465465
120   472745
121   478465
122   481443
123   488881
124   510001
125   510477
126   529995
127   541839
128   543973
129   565383
130   572757
131   576719
132   579123
133   581055
134   585497
135   586751
136   608829
137   621673
138   635035
139   638677
140   678681
141   683235
142   697901
143   718253
144   722201
145   723757
146   727597
147   727605
148   730205
149   747591
150   750915
151   775843
152   795833
153   795855
154   818155
155   830783
156   844223
157   849583
158   881787
159   884301
160   886557
161   887623
162   894621
163   911703
164   923705
165   926163
166   931685
167   975149
168   989667
169   1015869
170   1016515
171   1018601
172   1025075
173   1047765
174   1069317
175   1074195
176   1075543
177   1085603
178   1087935
179   1089403
180   1119235
181   1123719
182   1147125
183   1159021
184   1172535
185   1203147
186   1207317
187   1229831
188   1274139
189   1275409
190   1277913
191   1284175
192   1310943
193   1334729
194   1342129
195   1362971
196   1376277
197   1380141
198   1405849
199   1411007
200   1421251
201   1424955
202   1475027
203   1477455
204   1521325
205   1527525
206   1587993
207   1597485
208   1606969
209   1620045
210   1660945
211   1663493
212   1727193
213   1746289
214   1808481
215   1835331
216   1917071
217   1953367
218   1959685
219   1961155
220   1964853
221   1967811
222   1973559
223   2003301
224   2006745
225   2019243
226   2058875
227   2072985
228   2088957
229   2097885
230   2106207
231   2112279
232   2123949
233   2142839
234   2142855
235   2160925
236   2166603
237   2194101
238   2201883
239   2212811
240   2218833
241   2238691
242   2243721
243   2250885
244   2316619
245   2332281
246   2333463
247   2368049
248   2454603
249   2457345
250   2461569
251   2497257
252   2525265
253   2539197
254   2552125
255   2554695
256   2676549
257   2681945
258   2702527
259   2703561
260   2722681
261   2733485
262   2745939
263   2749747
264   2765115
265   2814273
266   2838829
267   2844219
268   2846061
269   2875689
270   2918175
271   2932007
272   2932797
273   2937645
274   2971885
275   3053931
276   3055493
277   3064677
278   3074295
279   3140393
280   3145181
281   3168025
282   3186939
283   3222147
284   3233097
285   3234777
286   3310439
287   3324895
288   3355443
289   3359579
290   3378465
291   3409513
292   3423321
293   3430635
294   3461223
295   3492585
296   3518199
297   3521259
298   3523989
299   3525585
300   3574303
301   3650013
302   3665385
303   3710811
304   3717237
305   3721081
306   3722509
307   3725729
308   3762735
309   3813775
310   3880109
311   3902435
312   3916341
313   3965433
314   3985905
315   3985921
316   4036925
317   4074939
318   4145915
319   4154161
320   4170411
321   4235679
322   4265041
323   4293401
324   4351457
325   4362633
326   4386105
327   4387565
328   4394113
329   4421551
330   4488075
331   4492631
332   4558515
333   4640391
334   4670029
335   4715095
336   4727859
337   4773483
338   4795819
339   4811355
340   4835209
341   4862973
342   4895695
343   5028311
344   5085009
345   5158425
346   5175303
347   5176317
348   5187525
349   5210303
350   5234593
351   5263845
352   5265825
353   5266563
354   5377333
355   5400687
356   5418021
357   5446443
358   5463711
359   5468517
360   5487951
361   5511415
362   5548757
363   5561279
364   5616611
365   5647791
366   5679411
367   5715879
368   5720525
369   5741469
370   5752911
371   5757645
372   5779137
373   5797561
374   5810427
375   5820035
376   5878125
377   5984271
378   5984607
379   6006627
380   6051627
381   6093493
382   6157463
383   6211035
384   6243385
385   6243405
386   6334475
387   6338059
388   6389955
389   6431425
390   6480621
391   6496469
392   6563297
393   6610043
394   6612705
395   6668361
396   6671665
397   6717503
398   6756915
399   6768075
400   6801795
401   6857015
402   6977123
403   6994361
404   7000875
405   7086943
406   7179831
407   7223419
408   7233031
409   7386273
410   7424409
411   7425627
412   7454821
413   7460205
414   7465955
415   7472537
416   7537275
417   7611825
418   7700825
419   7742055
420   7754945
421   7765345
422   7784091
423   7808059
424   7832419
425   7858345
426   7871871
427   7961703
428   8004087
429   8029425
430   8032409
431   8037315
432   8041121
433   8104761
434   8132855
435   8153145
436   8155925
437   8178885
438   8205123
439   8273345
440   8293275
441   8304699
442   8434125
443   8522469
444   8552713
445   8693025
446   8695655
447   8737509
448   8768793
449   9017745
450   9226189
451   9237523
452   9255633
453   9346055
454   9346855
455   9471287
456   9472527
457   9480947
458   9559815
459   9563925
460   9590175
461   9684665
462   9684675
463   9719637
464   9739707
465   9765157
466   9768895
467   9861033
468   9869655
469   9874645
470   9877935
471   9900513
472   9940743
473   9940745
?
```

The solutions upto $10^9$ that are prime are :

```
? x=0;y=1;forprime(n=3,10^9,y=y+1;if(Mod(y,znorder(Mod(2,n)))==0,x=x+1;print(x,"
   ",n,"   ",isprime(n,2))))
1   3   1
2   43   1
3   49477   1
4   4394113   1
5   33228911   1
6   40151873   1
7   57561767   1
8   80808961   1
9   189969337   1
?
```

Comment: Many thanks, a perfect work. I remember from my experiments that the majority of solutions are composite integers.

Comment: The sequence of solutions being also prime numbers starts as $3, 43 ,49477$.

Comment: I currently search for the prime solutions. The $9th$ prime solution is $189\ 969\ 337$. With the help of the $n$-th prime page, I determined $\pi(2\cdot 10^{13})$ and I incredibly found the solution $[20000019566469, 675896548500]$, where $n$ is the first number and $\pi(n)$ the second.

Comment: Many thanks for the information and attention about this question. I think that this post has many possibilities to be interesting for many other people.

Comment: The ones in the last columns just mean that the primilaty was proven. They are probably obsolete.